# Windows, how to find out what processes access BaseNamedObjects (shared memory)

Tags: winapi, shared-memory

Is it possible to find out what process creates shared memory?

I just learned that I have a lot of shared memory (CreateFileMapping, shared memory, named pipes), so I'd like to figure out what creates those. I suspect that I have a malware.

More details here https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16442/what-is-sessions-1-basenamedobjects-namedbuffer

Comment: `NamedBuffer, mAH, Process $00001360, API $77a7dffe` this is section object (file mapping if want) and it created by 0x1360 process. if you look for this process you found that this is devenv.exe (so msvc). the `77a7dffe` is address and by this address some hook (jump dword ptr[xx]) is set.

Comment: Question title and question text ask for different things. Besides that, it doesn't appear that your question is about a programming problem. Please take the [tour] to learn what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: well i need both, processes that create and processes that access.